# "Unrelated" stored procedures causes deadlock

Tags: sql-server-2019, deadlock

The title says "unrelated" because that's what they are supposed to be but apparently not...

I've got two stored procedures (`log_sequence_event` and `log_se_event`) that causes a deadlock and I've got no clue to why. They are called by the same Python app in different threads through PYODBC with autocommit off. The threads do a max of 2000 calls before committing.
`sequence` and `se` are not to be confused with each other, they are completely unrelated.

Both procedures makes an insert to their respective tables (`fact.sequence` and `fact.se`) and each table has a separate indexed view on it (`v_daily_fact_sequence` and `v_daily_fact_se`).
The procedure `log_se_event` does a select (with join) from the tables `dim.se` and `dim.network` (which has no connection to sequences) before the insert to `fact.se`. The `log_sequence_event` isn't doing anything before the insert.

If I understand the deadlock report correctly the deadlock happens when `log_sequence_event` holds a `RangeS-U` lock on the index for view `v_daily_fact_se` and `log_se_event` holds a `RangeS-U` lock on the index for view `v_daily_fact_sequence` and they then want a lock for the other index. This is (for me) the wtf part, **why is `log_sequence_event` holding a lock on the index for `v_daily_fact_se` and vice versa?**
This is on my laptop running SQL Server 2019 Developers Edition.

The parts involved:

- The procs:

```
create procedure [ETL_1.7.1].log_sequence_event
(
    @terminal_id int,
    @terminal_row_id bigint,
    @timestamp datetime2(3),
    @id int,
    @event int,
    @energy int,
    @duration int,
    @weight int = null,
    @no_of_dvs int,
    @average_fill_degree int --not used
)
as
    if (@event < 100)
        insert into fact.sequence
        (
            terminal_id,
            terminal_row_id,
            [timestamp],
            sequence_id,
            event_type_id,
            pred_kwh,
            pred_dv_count,
            pred_duration,
            pred_collected_weight,
            actual_kwh,
            actual_dv_count,
            actual_duration,
            actual_collected_weight
        )
        values
        (
            @terminal_id,--terminal_id,
            @terminal_row_id,--terminal_row_id,
            @timestamp,--[timestamp],
            @id,--sequence_id,
            @event,--event_type_id,
            @energy,--pred_kwh,
            @no_of_dvs,--pred_dv_count,
            @duration,--pred_duration,
            @weight,--pred_collected_weight,
            0,--actual_kwh,
            0,--actual_dv_count,
            0,--actual_duration,
            0--actual_collected_weight
        )
    else
        insert into fact.sequence
        (
            terminal_id,
            terminal_row_id,
            [timestamp],
            sequence_id,
            event_type_id,
            pred_kwh,
            pred_dv_count,
            pred_duration,
            pred_collected_weight,
            actual_kwh,
            actual_dv_count,
            actual_duration,
            actual_collected_weight
        )
        values
        (
            @terminal_id,--terminal_id,
            @terminal_row_id,--terminal_row_id,
            @timestamp,--[timestamp],
            @id,--sequence_id,
            @event,--event_type_id,
            0,--pred_kwh,
            0,--pred_dv_count,
            0,--pred_duration,
            0,--pred_collected_weight,
            @energy,--actual_kwh,
            @no_of_dvs,--actual_dv_count,
            @duration,--actual_duration,
            @weight--actual_collected_weight
        )
go


create procedure [ETL_1.7.1].log_se_event
(
    @terminal_id int,
    @terminal_row_id bigint,
    @timestamp datetime2(3),
    @id int,
    @event int
)
as
    declare @vcm_id int = 0

    select
        @vcm_id = [address]
    from dim.se se
    join dim.network net
        on se.terminal_id = net.terminal_id and se.network = net.id
    where se.terminal_id = @terminal_id
        and se.se = @id
        and network_type = 6

    insert into fact.se
    (
        terminal_id,
        terminal_row_id,
        [timestamp],
        se,
        event_id,
        repeat_count,
        error_code,
        network,
        vcm_id
    )
    values
    (
        @terminal_id,
        @terminal_row_id,
        @timestamp,
        @id,
        @event,--event_id,
        0,--repeat_count,
        0,--error_code,
        (select d.network from dim.se d where d.terminal_id = @terminal_id and d.se = @id),--network,
        @vcm_id
    )
go
```

- The tables and related indexed view definitions:

```
create table fact.sequence
(
    terminal_id int not null,
    terminal_row_id bigint not null,
    [timestamp] datetime2(3) not null,

    sequence_id int not null,
    event_type_id int not null,
    pred_kwh int not null,
    pred_dv_count int not null,
    pred_duration int not null, --seconds
    pred_collected_weight int not null, --kg
    actual_kwh int not null,
    actual_dv_count int not null,
    actual_duration int not null, --seconds
    actual_collected_weight int not null, --kg

    constraint pk__fact_sequence primary key (terminal_id, terminal_row_id),
    constraint fk__fact_sequence__dim_sequence foreign key (terminal_id, sequence_id) references dim.sequence(terminal_id, id),
    constraint fk__fact_sequence__enum_sequence_event foreign key (event_type_id) references enum.sequence_event (id)
)

go
create view staging.v_daily_fact_sequence
with schemabinding
as
    SELECT
        cast(fs.[timestamp] as date) [date],
        fs.terminal_id,
        fs.sequence_id,
        fs.event_type_id,
        count_big(*) as [count],
        sum(fs.actual_kwh) sum_kwh,
        sum(fs.actual_dv_count) sum_dv_count,
        sum(fs.actual_duration) sum_duration,
        sum(fs.actual_collected_weight) sum_kg
    FROM [fact].[sequence] fs
    group by
        cast([timestamp] as date),
        fs.terminal_id,
        sequence_id,
        event_type_id
go
create unique clustered index uci__staging__fact_sequence on staging.v_daily_fact_sequence([date], terminal_id, sequence_id, event_type_id)
go



create table fact.se
(
    terminal_id int not null,
    terminal_row_id bigint not null,
    [timestamp] datetime2(3) not null,

    se int not null,
    event_id int not null,
    repeat_count int not null,
    error_code int not null,
    network int not null,
    vcm_id int not null,

    constraint pk__fact_se primary key (terminal_id, terminal_row_id),
    constraint fk__fact_se__dim_se foreign key (terminal_id, se) references dim.se(terminal_id, se),
    constraint fk__fact_se__enum_valve_event foreign key (event_id) references enum.valve_event (id)
)

go
create view staging.v_daily_fact_se
with schemabinding
as
    select
        cast([timestamp] as date) [date],
        terminal_id,
        se,
        event_id,
        count_big(*) as [count]
    from fact.se
    group by
        cast([timestamp] as date),
        terminal_id,
        se,
        event_id
go
create unique clustered index uci__staging__fact_se on staging.v_daily_fact_se([date], terminal_id, se, event_id)
go
```

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process2742b6a5848" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process2742b6a5848" taskpriority="0" logused="351972" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594049855488 (1c280247b0f1)" waittime="2388" ownerId="8532120" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-11-02T11:48:16.683" XDES="0x273c207c428" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="11" kpid="30304" status="suspended" spid="61" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-11-02T11:48:17.697" lastbatchcompleted="2022-11-02T11:48:17.697" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.697" clientapp="Python" hostname="ENE-5CD9245PJR" hostpid="30564" loginname="etl" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="8532120" currentdb="5" currentdbname="EDW" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="EDW.ETL_1.7.1.log_sequence_event" line="50" stmtstart="2510" stmtend="4352" sqlhandle="0x03000500e1ab652609eeba0041af000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
insert into fact.sequence
        (
            terminal_id,
            terminal_row_id,
            [timestamp],
            sequence_id,
            event_type_id,
            pred_kwh,
            pred_dv_count,
            pred_duration,
            pred_collected_weight,
            actual_kwh,
            actual_dv_count,
            actual_duration,
            actual_collected_weight
        )
        values
        (
            @terminal_id,--terminal_id,
            @terminal_row_id,--terminal_row_id,
            @timestamp,--[timestamp],
            @id,--sequence_id,
            @event,--event_type_id,
            0,--pred_kwh,
            0,--pred_dv_count,
            0,--pred_duration,
            0,--pred_collected_weight,
            @energy,--actual_kwh,
            @no_of_dvs,--actual_dv_count,
            @duration,--actual_duration,
            @weight--actual_collected_weight    </frame>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="218" stmtend="588" sqlhandle="0x0100050095e97700e09e97017402000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC [ETL_1.7.1].log_sequence_event @timestamp=@P1,@id=@P2,@event=@P3,@energy=@P4,@duration=@P5,@weight=@P6,@no_of_dvs=@P7,@average_fill_degree=@P8,@terminal_id=@P9,@terminal_row_id=@P1    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@P1 nvarchar(46),@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int,@P9 int,@P10 bigint)set nocount on;EXEC [ETL_1.7.1].log_sequence_event @timestamp=@P1,@id=@P2,@event=@P3,@energy=@P4,@duration=@P5,@weight=@P6,@no_of_dvs=@P7,@average_fill_degree=@P8,@terminal_id=@P9,@terminal_row_id=@P10   </inputbuf>
    </process>
    <process id="process2742b06d468" taskpriority="0" logused="770436" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594049658880 (ffffffffffff)" waittime="2426" ownerId="8529120" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2022-11-02T11:48:15.520" XDES="0x273c2164428" lockMode="RangeS-U" schedulerid="4" kpid="36140" status="suspended" spid="60" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2022-11-02T11:48:17.657" lastbatchcompleted="2022-11-02T11:48:17.657" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.657" clientapp="Python" hostname="ENE-5CD9245PJR" hostpid="30564" loginname="etl" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="8529120" currentdb="5" currentdbname="EDW" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="EDW.ETL_1.7.1.log_se_event" line="22" stmtstart="872" stmtend="1872" sqlhandle="0x03000500c4f6a02105eeba0041af000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
insert into fact.se
    (
        terminal_id,
        terminal_row_id,
        [timestamp],
        se,
        event_id,
        repeat_count,
        error_code,
        network,
        vcm_id
    )
    values
    (
        @terminal_id,
        @terminal_row_id,
        @timestamp,
        @id,
        @event,--event_id,
        0,--repeat_count,
        0,--error_code,
        (select d.network from dim.se d where d.terminal_id = @terminal_id and d.se = @id),--network,
        @vcm_id    </frame>
        <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="136" stmtend="336" sqlhandle="0x01000500b1ea553470ff35ee7302000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC [ETL_1.7.1].log_se_event @timestamp=@P1,@id=@P2,@event=@P3,@terminal_id=@P4,@terminal_row_id=@P    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
(@P1 nvarchar(46),@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 bigint)set nocount on;EXEC [ETL_1.7.1].log_se_event @timestamp=@P1,@id=@P2,@event=@P3,@terminal_id=@P4,@terminal_row_id=@P5   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594049855488" dbid="5" objectname="EDW.staging.v_daily_fact_sequence" indexname="uci__staging__fact_sequence" id="lock2740ecc4e00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594049855488">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process2742b06d468" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process2742b6a5848" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057594049658880" dbid="5" objectname="EDW.staging.v_daily_fact_se" indexname="uci__staging__fact_se" id="lock27317245700" mode="RangeS-U" associatedObjectId="72057594049658880">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process2742b6a5848" mode="RangeS-U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process2742b06d468" mode="RangeS-U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: Do you commit after each proc call? Do the procs touch other tables before the insert?

Comment: I commit after each batch which is maximum 2000 calls. `log_se_event` makes a select from the tables `dim.se` and `dim.network` before the insert, sequences has no connection to those two tables.
I've updated the question with this info.

Comment: Are there any other objects in place that can connect any of the `se` to `sequence` objects, such as foreign keys, check constraints, triggers, etc? Or are you sure all `se` objects are completely isolated from all `sequence` objects?

Comment: it's a little odd that both owner and victim processes have two open transactions. can you post the code that leads to the deadlocks?

Comment: @J.D. The only thing I can find is that the `fact.sequence` and `fact.se` have foreign keys to their respective `dim.sequence` and `dim.se` tables which in turn has a foreign key to the `dim.terminal` table.

Comment: @ErikDarling is it the @trancount=2 you are referring to? I'll see if I can figure out where that comes from. I've added the full definitions for the stored procedures.

Comment: autocommit=off so @@trancount is going to be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have autocommit off, you're probably writing a transaction runs both stored procedures, and still holds locks from a previous invocation.

So a session that owns an X lock on v_daily_fact_se tries to get a range lock v_daily_fact_sequence, but another session already owns an X lock on a key in the range, and so becomes blocked.  Then the session owning the X lock on v_daily_fact_sequence tries to acquire a range lock on v_daily_fact_se and becomes blocked by the first session.

So audit your python code to ensure that no session writes to both tables in a transaction.

Comment: That would explain it since it can definitely happen that two threads write to the same table during sessions that overlap in time. I guess I got to hung up on the fact that the deadlock report mentioned these two unrelated procedures.